# Turning down a web server from a running container via bash

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` to start a webserver with PHP.

```
version: "2.0"

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./web:/web
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

  php:
    image: php:${PHP_VERSION}-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./web:/web
```

After running `docker-compose up`, I can access my website perfectly at `http://localhost:8000`. But if I then access the nginx container, with:

```
$ docker-compose run nginx bash
```

and within the container I run:

```
$ service nginx stop
```

I still can see the website `http://localhost:8000` being displayed in the browser.

How can it be that after stopping the server in the container, the website is still being delivered?

Comment: I bet nginx isn't run as a service.

Answer (score 0):

The `docker-compose run` command starts a new container, you're stopping nginx in that new container, what you want is `docker attach nginx`

The documentation is located [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/).